# monkey webserver cgi configuration

Tags: webserver

i installed monkey webserver, the html static pages are working.

I want to configure cgi execution in monkey webserver.

I compiled with cgi plugin, and monkey executable is loading with cgi plugin.
I enabled HANDLERS for cgi (Match /cgi-bin/.*.\cgi  cgi) in monkey/conf/sites/default file.

I CAN NOT find cgi.conf inside conf/plugins/ directory.  and not sure how to enable a cgi-bin directory path for scripts.

I create monkey/cgi-bin directory and tried writing a (hello.c) C file hello world program and renamed the the executable file as hello.cgi and tried executing through http://localhost:8888/cgi-bin/hello.cgi.  But it says 'unable to connect.'

then i tried moving the cgi-bin directory in monkey/htdocs folder, it gives black page.

Want some one to help how to configure cgi-bin path on monkey web server.

Comment: after long struggle found cgi-bin folder should be inside htdocs folder. its working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have cgi-bin folder inside htdocs folder. Cgi should work.